# iOS7 Safari Fullscreen Image-Size to small when scrolling (hide url-bar etc.)

Tags: ios, css, safari, ios7, mobile-safari

i have made an website with fullscreen background slider/image. I have used "backstretch", see here: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

It works nearly everywhere. On the current Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox on Mac and Windows and even on IE10, IE9 and IE8 on Windows. Mobile, too - works on the old Android Browser, Android Chrome, iOS (all Versions) Chrome and on iOS 4, 5, 6.x Safari.

But not on Safari on iOS 7.

The problem: If you scroll down the url bar and the bar on the bottom hide. But the image does not scale up to be as big as the screen. A white bar at the bottom appears, as high as the hidden toolbars are.

Im sure that this is not a problem with my code. Google Crome for example works the same way - the bars hide when scrolling - but the image scales up to fit the "new bigger screen".

Other fullscreen background image website make the same problem on iOS 7 Safari.

Have anyone a solution for this problem?
And: Is this just "different" made and i have to code different or is this a bug, which is not wanted by Apple?

Sorry for this buggy English!! :D

Thank you for you help. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just add this**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

before  tag